# if spinner changed

Tags: android

i want execute populateFields if the spinner changed but i don't know how i can do it.
i need anything like a onclicklistener or else

java:

---

```
            private String abfrage;


            on create:

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStd);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinnerZeitauswahl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            abfrage = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            populateFields();




            populateFields:

            int j = 10;
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
            {
                    if(abfrage.equals(arr[i]))//works
                    mFehlzeitText.setText(String.valueOf(j));
                    j+=10;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29). I guess you want smth like this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                populateFields();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                populateFields();
            }
        }
    );
```